# Calling a color from xml file

Tags: android, android-xml

If i have an xml file with custom colors like this in res/values/colors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>
 <drawable name="red">#ff0000</drawable>
 <drawable name="blue">#0000ff</drawable>
 <drawable name="green">#00ff00</drawable>
</resources>
```

How can I use colors or other values from it in other code?

How can I use these for arguments? Something like:

```
    int green = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green);
    g.drawRect(1, 1, 181, 121, green);
```

gives errors in logcat and crashes the program. So if colors.xml is in res/values/
and I have context imported how can I use green, for example in an argument?

Comment: why you not using this <color name="red">#ff0000</color> instead of <drawable name="red">#ff0000</drawable>. If you can follw this then @anthropomo answer will definitely help you.

Comment: A very good point, @Narendra! Updating my answer...

Comment: Last argument in drawRect is of type Paint, so you have to create a Paint like the one in the answer and then supply it as the last argument. I was new not too long ago. GUI is tough in every language I learn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change `drawable` to `color` in your xml.

Then you need to have context. It goes like this:

`context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green);`

It returns an int color value.

Edit:

For other values, see the functions here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html

I like tp get all my xml colors once and pass them around from there so I am not typing the above over and over. Not sure if this is considered best practice.

If you want to use this in a Paint, it could be:

```
// Declare this at the beginning:
Paint green paint;
// This goes in the constructor:
greenPaint = new Paint();
greenPaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
// then draw something in onDraw, for example:
canvas.drawRect(5,5,5,5, greenPaint);
```

If you want to use it in multiple Paints, etc. save it as an int:

```
int greenNum = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green);
```